# How to assign a value to nested object by varying key?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have nested objects, for example:

```
var a = {b: {c: {d: 1}}};
```

and a dynamic key:

```
var field = "b.c.d"
```

I need to change a value at object `a` by key `b.c.d`. Nesting level of object and key can vary.
The only thing which works for me is:

```
eval("a."+field+"=2"); -> it means a.b.c.d = 2;
```

But it's ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following using a recursive function

```js
var a = {b: {c: {d: 1}}};
var field = "b.c.d";
var value = 2;

function updateObject(obj, key, val){
  if(obj) {
    if(key.includes(".")) {
      var keys = key.split(".");
      updateObject(obj[keys.shift()], keys.join("."), val);
    } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key] = val;
  }
}

updateObject(a, field, value);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a recursive function to update the value:

```js
var a = {b: {c: {d: 1}}};
function updateValue(obj, path,value){
  if(typeof path == "string")
    path = path.split(".");
   if(path.length == 1)
    obj[path[0]] = value;
   else
    updateValue(obj[path[0]], path.slice(1), value);
}

updateValue(a, "b.c.d", 2);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, in case you have to use the same path several times and want to create a function you can use to set the value:

```js
var a = {b: {c: {d: 1}}};

function createSetter(path) {
  return path.split(".")
    .reverse()
    .reduce((setter, key) => 
        (setter
          ? (o,value) => setter(o[key],value)
          : (o,value) => o[key]=value
        ), null)
}
  
var myBCDSetter = createSetter("b.c.d")

myBCDSetter(a,2)
console.log(a)

myBCDSetter(a,3)
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash `_.set(object, path, value)`. In your case `_.set(a, "b.c.d", 2)`

Refer to docs [here](https://lodash.com/docs/#set)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Function constructor, it works with arrays too:

```
Object.prototype.modify = function (path,value){
    let a = Function("object","path","value","object"+path+"=value"); 
    a(this,path,value)
}

var a = {b: {c: {d: 1}}};    
var b = {b: {c: {d: [1,[10,20,30],3,4,5]}}};

a.modify(".b.c.d", 3)//<-- change value 

b.modify(".b.c.d[1][0]", "new Value")//<-- change value 

console.log(a)

console.log(b.b.c)
```